# Когда правильно употреблять точку с запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, точка-с-запятой

В каких случаях следует ставить точку с запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В сложных предложениях, если их части очень различаются по смыслу.
   Пример: *"Солнце освещало пустырь; когда-то тут стояла деревня"*.
2. В перечислениях пунктов.
   Пример:
   *-русский язык;
   -украинский язык;*
   После точки с запятой нужно писать с маленькой буквы.

Comment: Что за самосуд?

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что после запятой пишут с большой буквы, с маленькой пишут - нам в школе так говорили.

Comment: А где Вы увидели, чтобы было сказано, что с большой??

Comment: Другими словами — невозможно предположить, что кто-то после тчк/зпт пишет с прописной. Это же очевидно.

Comment: Удалил бы не только этот комментарий (т. к. — не ответ), но и сам вопрос..

Answer (score 0):

Если части бессоюзного сложного предложения распространены.
"Изумрудные лягушки прыгают под ногами; между корней, подняв золотую головку, лежит уж и стережёт их".